# How to re-organize (reshaping) my dataset moving multiple columns into rows?

Tags: r

I want to re-organize a longitudinal dataset in R. The original dataset looks like the one below.

| ID | y1_demo | y2_demo | y1_ex | y2_ex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | B | A | B |
| 200 | B | A | A | C |

I would like to see the output like the following.

| ID | Year | demo | ex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Y1 | A | A |
| 100 | Y2 | B | B |
| 200 | Y1 | B | A |
| 200 | Y2 | A | C |

Comment: You may use `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -ID, names_to = c('Year', '.value'), names_sep = '_')` where `df` is your dataset name.

Comment: Another option:   `pivot_longer(df,cols = -ID, names_pattern = "^(.*?)_demo", names_to = "Year", names_transform = list(Year = toupper), values_to = "Demo")`